# SQL - Swap/Interchange field values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thanks for all your help! Here's another one...

**Situation:**

Our company operates from 8AM - 6PM.
We use biometric device for attendance.
Employee will click "IN" or "OUT" first on the device before pressing it's finger to know if it's IN(AM) or OUT(PM).

**Problem:**

Some employees wrongly click "OUT" on the device and press their fingers as they check IN, registering it as OUT(AM).. and vice versa, IN(PM).

Below is a sample data for reference:

```
EmpID    LogTime                  CheckType
1        4/4/2017 7:24:22 AM      OUT
1        4/4/2017 18:02:11 PM     IN
```

One employee hit "OUT" but the time is considered "IN" early in the morning. And hit "IN" when leaving the office in the afternoon.

**Question:**

Using **SQL**(SQL Server), how can I interchange their checktypes?

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: What if somebody leaves for an hour and comes back? I.e. IN, OUT, IN and OUT the same day?

Comment: Is it absolutely definite that they are only IN before noon, and only OUT after noon?

Comment: @jarlh I have a code to get the First IN, Last OUT. It's working fine except for the problem I posted above :(

Comment: I see no alternatives to writing a SQL procedure using SQL Server's T-SQL, to swap the values, much like writing a program to swap values between A and B (assigning A to a temp variable, then a to b, and temp to a).

Comment: @BeanFrog the company uses the device for decades. So let's say I'm the one to do the adjustments. Sad life.

Comment: Do you mean "ignore the button pressed type, rely on timestamp only" ?

Comment: @Serg the device automatically determines AM or PM.. but some dumb employees still clicks on the IN or OUT button. I already suggested to the management if there's a way to avoid employees click on the button, or a device replacement at least, the one without a button.

Comment: @Jorz It's probably cheaper to have you ask on Stack Overflow, hence they never upgraded :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
Update attendance set checkType = 'IN' where LogTime between <min range> and <max range>
```

Give a range for morning time similar is the case with checkout.

Comment: Woah.. I never thought of that! I'll give this a try and hopefully accept this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: no problem :) similarily you'll do it for checkout too.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work in all cases.  This never assigns `OUT` to anything.  For instance, this may fail in the case where an employee arrives at work very late, and then leaves shortly thereafter.

Comment: alternatively, I can use RIGHT(LogTime ,2) to determine if it's AM or PM.. then update the appropriate checkType. In my case somehow, it works. unless our company will operate 24hrs a day.

Comment: may bad..  deleted accepted answer.. i forgot that employees sometimes go to work half-day.. IN and OUT on PM or AM (ex. 1PM-6PM )

Answer (score 1):

My strategy is to assign a row number to each pair of employee records.  However, we assign a row number ordering by both the log time and the check type.  If the order be correct, then viewing a given employee record pair ascending by date, *both* row numbers should be in lock step as 1-2.  However, if the order be reversed, then we should see 1-2 for the log time, but 21 for the check type.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT EmpID, LogTime, CheckType,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY LogTime) rn1,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY CheckType) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)
UPDATE cte
SET CheckType = CASE WHEN CheckType = 'OUT' THEN 'IN' ELSE 'OUT' END
WHERE rn1 <> rn2
```

The following table might show what I have in mind:

```
EmpID    LogTime                  CheckType    rn1    rn2
1        4/4/2017 7:24:22 AM      OUT          1      2
1        4/4/2017 18:02:11 PM     IN           2      1
```

If employee `1` had logged his time correctly, we would see this:

```
EmpID    LogTime                  CheckType    rn1    rn2
1        4/4/2017 7:24:22 AM      OUT          1      1
1        4/4/2017 18:02:11 PM     IN           2      2
```

In other words, both computed row numbers would be the same.

Here is a **demo** of the CTE I used with your sample data:

## Rextester

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near 't'.

Comment: I removed the alias from the update.  Please try again.

Comment: it works.. but with wrong result.. AM/PM is mixed up randomly with IN/OUT

Comment: Wait... you didn't store _text_ into `LogTime`, did you?

Comment: Removed my accepted answer. I'm now considering to this one. The problem is that, LogTime is saved as a varchar. Possibly the reason why error occured when I ran your code.

Comment: Not possibly, _definitely_.  You're going to need to convert to some sort of date type, and I'm not sure that can be done.  I tried with `CONVERT()` but it failed.